# Function undefined when assigned to variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on some authentication in React using Firebase as the backend.

I have a function to check if a user exists that works as I expect:

```
checkIfUserExists(uid) {
  ref.child('users').child(uid).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      console.log("User exists");
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log("User does not exist");
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

When I call it passing a uid, it will write to the console if the user exists or not.

```
this.checkIfUserExists(userId);
```

I want to just get a boolean representation of whether the user is logged in or not, but trying to do something like this will always print "No user".

```
if (this.checkIfUserExists(userId)) {
  console.log('The user does really exist');
} else {
  console.log('No user');      
}
```

If i try to

```
console.log(this.checkIfUserExists(userId));
```

The console outputs "undefined".

Am i approaching this the wrong way? Why is it undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return statement inside the inner function will not return the value through the outer function. Instead try sending a function like this

```
checkIfUserExists(uid, callback) {
  ref.child('users').child(uid).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    callback.call(null, snapshot.exists());
  });
};

checkIfUserExists(uid, function(exists){
  if(exists){
    console.log("User exists");
  }else{
    console.log("User does not exist"); 
  }
});
```

**[More on .call() here in documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)**

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I'm starting to grasp the concept of callbacks now.